# Can I design Arduino Mega 2560 circuit without adding ATMega 16?

Tags: pcb-design

I want to make Arduino Mega 2560 board.
As the reference files are given on Arduino Site, I don't want to add USB communication on the board.
So can I remove part of ATMega 16?
Will it cause any kind of problem in working of board?
And if It will fine to remove ATMega 16 part, How much part of schematic to be change?

Comment: It would be helpful for you to understand what each part does. If you find the Atmega16 useful, you should just add it, if not, your question is answered. :)

Comment: Yes @WesleyLee , due to finding more stuff on web I got confused whether it is ok or not and I got proper solution here. Thanks.

Comment: When I omit a USB / Serial IC I often put an "FTDI" header, so I can use common USB/Serial converters. Might be useful in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can omit the ATmega16U2 and its accompanying parts. That is, the whole right block of schematic in [this sheet](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560_R3-sch.pdf).

The resulting board will work perfectly fine, it will simply no longer have a built-in programming interface, nor a built-in USB-serial interface. You will likely want to buy an FTDI cable and an AVR programmer, if you do not already have these.

Comment: Hi uint128_t, Your answer cleared my confusion and solved my problem. Thanks man.